# locking a textarea using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I "lock" a textarea with jQuery so that no more characters can be entered?  I don't want to necessarily disable it since I want to allow characters to be deleted.

**update:** oops..it just came to me:
if I am limiting the length to say 400 characters then i can use the following when the length is > 400:

```
this.value = this.value.substring(0, 400);
```

which will just trim the excess

Comment: Just a point about all the solutions below:  none of them prevent mouse-based copy-paste into a textarea.

Comment: Also, be sure that you validate the character count server-side. Client-side validation isn't safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

following is quick contraption from modification of jquery.numeric plugin :)

It allows special keys but don't let user type anything.

```
<textarea id="txt" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#txt").keypress(function(e){
         var key = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : 0;
         // allow Ctrl+A
         if((e.ctrlKey && key == 97 /* firefox */) || (e.ctrlKey && key == 65) 
                                     /* opera */) return true;
         // allow Ctrl+X (cut)
         if((e.ctrlKey && key == 120 /* firefox */) || (e.ctrlKey && key == 88) 
                                     /* opera */) return true;
         // allow Ctrl+C (copy)
         if((e.ctrlKey && key == 99 /* firefox */) || (e.ctrlKey && key == 67) 
                                     /* opera */) return true;
         // allow Ctrl+Z (undo)
         if((e.ctrlKey && key == 122 /* firefox */) || (e.ctrlKey && key == 90) 
                                     /* opera */) return true;
         // allow or deny Ctrl+V (paste), Shift+Ins
         if((e.ctrlKey && key == 118 /* firefox */) || (e.ctrlKey && key == 86) 
                                     /* opera */
         || (e.shiftKey && key == 45)) return true;
         //page up, down, home end, left-right-up-down
         if(key > 32 && key < 40) return true;

         // if DEL or BACKSPACE is pressed
         return key == 46 || key == 8;

   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to get rid of those comments by using descriptive constants instead of key codes? `if (e.ctrlKey && key == keys[CTRL_A]) ...`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("textarea").keypress(function(){ 
  if($(this).val().length>=10) 
    return false; 
});
```

Demo here:
http://jsbin.com/erama

Answer (score 0):

You could bind to the keypress/keydown event of the textarea and block out all characters except backspace and delete. This way the user can delete characters but can't add/remove new characters.

You bind to the keypress event like this:

```
$('#text-area').keypress(function(e) {});
```

Then you can use the keyCode property of the event object (argument e) that is passed to check if the pressed key is delete or backspace. You can find [more information on the keypress event](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/keypress) on the jquery website.

You can base yourself on a [list of keycodes](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/c4/702b8cd1-e5b0-42e6-83ac-25f0306e3e25/Javascript-Char-Codes-Key-Codes.aspx) to only allow delete and backspace. In this case keyCode should be equal to 8 or 46.

So the resulting code would be something like this (not tested though):

```
$('#text-area').keypress(function(e) { if(e.keyCode != 8 && e.keyCode != 46) { e.preventDefault(); } });
```

The preventDefault function of the event will stop any further processing, so if the characters is not delete or backspace it will not be typed.

Comment: You have to take care of other events also. User can also drop text and paste text.

Comment: this is much more sophisticated than my approach of just trimming off the excess once the max is reached...maybe this is overly complicated for what I need?

Comment: As phoenix points out, this is not (yet) flawless and if you can achieve what you need with the code your solution, which is much lesser code, I would certainly go with that solution.

@phoenix
I would expect that pasting also is a keypress event (when using ctrl+v), I would need to test that out though? Although the different actions with the mouse should also be caught that's right.

Answer (score 0):

Here is plugin to limit input to textboxes/textareas

```
    jQuery.fn.charlimit = function(prompt, limit) {
        this.keyup(function(e) {
            var txt = $(this).val();
            var c = txt.length;

            if (prompt != null || prompt != 'undefined') {
                $(prompt).html((limit - c) + " chars left.");
            }
            if (c > limit) {
                $(this).val(txt.substring(0, limit));
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
        return this;
    }
```

**prompt** can be any span/div etc to show prompt message.

Comment: That `prompt != null || prompt != 'undefined'` doesn't really guard from nonexistent element. Did you mean - `if (typeof prompt != 'undefined')`?